# Ant doesn't find the package imported in Java test class

Tags: java, junit, ant, compiler-errors, build.xml

I have a build file where I have added code for compiling java test classes.  I want to run junit test with Ant for those compiled test classes. But the problem is: Ant complains that the package which I have imported in test class doesn't exist and it fails to compile the test class.

My folder structure is mentioned below:

```
Java source class => src > java > com > nov > pro > pal > excel
Java test class (srcTestClass) => src > test > junit 
compiled Java source class => ant > tmp > classes > com > nov > pro > pal > excel
compiled Java test class (destTestClass) => ant > folderForTestClass > testClasses > junit
build file location  => ant > build.xml
```

The compile-test section of my build file is:

```
 <target name="compile-test">
<echo message="*** compile test ***"/>
<javac includeantruntime="false" encoding="ISO-8859-1" srcdir="${srcTestClass}" destdir="${destTestClass}" classpathref="classpath.test" debug="${debug}" debuglevel="lines,vars,source">
<!-- compilerarg value="-Xlint:unchecked"/ -->
  <src path="${srcTestClass}"/>
  <classpath>
      <fileset dir="${lib}" >
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
      </fileset>
      <fileset dir="${excelPackage}" >
        <include name="**/*.class"/>
      </fileset>
  </classpath>
</javac>
```

[I have added the picture of error message here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esG2c.png)

Comment: Have you verified the correctness of `${lib}`?

Comment: @VGR Yes lib folder contains all jar files and it is working fine. The complain is about the package that I imported from Java source class. And it's not related with jar file

Comment: Is the class you’re trying to import in the `com.nov.pro.pal.excel` package?

Comment: @VGR Yes that is the package (I have written package name in short cut), I have added error message picture as well for more clarification.

Comment: Copying the Ant output into your question as a formatted text block is far more useful than a picture.  That aside, the ant/tmp/classes directory doesn’t appear to be in your javac classpath, so it’s no surprise that the compiler isn’t aware of its existence.  Or does one of the jars under `${lib}` contain that package?

Comment: @VGR, so in  javac classpath should I use compiled Java test class or Java source class? and thank you for suggestion of copying Ant output in to the question.

Comment: Inside the classpath, add something like `<pathelement location="ant/tmp/classes"/>`.  (Unless of course you have defined a variable for ant/tmp/classes, in which case use that.)

Comment: @VGR I have added class path. But Ant gives same error message. I have edited above build file code, would you please check if that is the right way to do?

Comment: Do not add a fileset.  .class files are not valid classpath entries.  However, a directory, in which resides a package containing compiled classes, *is* a valid classpath entry.  That is why I suggested a `<pathelement>`.

Comment: @VGR ... as you suggested I added <pathelement location="ant/tmp/classes"/> and now Ant compiles the test class properly. Thank you very much for you valuable suggestion. I appreciated :)